# oracle with JDBC delete account funtion

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I am trying to create a method that deletes a user account from an Oracle database but whenever the code `ps.executeUpdate() > 0` executes the program does not return anything or terminate. I tried the query straight into the database and it worked. any ideas why?

```
public boolean deleteAccount(int account_ID) {

     try {
         System.out.println("This is read");
         Connection conn = Jdbcconnection.getConnection();
         String sql = "DELETE FROM ACCOUNTS where account_ID = ?"; 

         System.out.println("This is read");            

         PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         ps.setInt(1, account_ID);

         System.out.println("This is read");   

         return ps.executeUpdate() > 0;

    } catch(SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you roll back the delete you did through your client? Sounds like it's just blocked.

Comment: Can you check the connection with the database ? I do think your code is OK.

Comment: wow stupid mistake on my part, forgot to commit the data so it shows in the developer but not in JDBC.